# How to say that something is the same regarding each pair in a group of different pairs of things?

Tags: word-usage, writing, writing-advice

They are two scenarios that I am comparing. Each scenario has 2 variation that slightly differ from one another. The first variation of the first scenario parallels the first variation of the second scenario, and the second variation of the first scenario parallels the second variation of the second scenario. The number of people involved in each variation in each scenario is the same as the number of people involved in its counterpart in the other scenario.

Now I want to say the content of the last sentence differently as something as

> The number of involved people are the same **in each of the paralleling variations**.

or

> The number of involved people are the same **in each pair of the
>   paralleling variations**.

Which way of saying the strong part is correct/preferred? Or maybe both are problematic?

Comment: Would 'corresponds with' suit your meaning better, rather than 'paralleling'?

Comment: @marcellothearcane You mean "in each pair of the corresponding variations"?

Comment: Yes, that could work.  If the number has been previously defined, you could drop the 'pair' to get 'in the corresponding variations'.  Or maybe you could phrase it: 'The number of people involved corresponds in each variation' or similar.

Comment: I think *corresponds* needs some assistance in this context. It doesn't actually mean equal to each other. You have to state that S1V1 corresponds to S2V1 and S1V2 corresponds to S2V2. Then you have to say that the corresponding variations have equal numbers of people. On the other hand, *respective* can be used to indicate the relationships based on the word order in the statement.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your groups. Am I right in thinking that you mean something like this? Group one consists of men and women wearing black, group two consists of men and women wearing blue, and in each group there are five men and six women. That is the number of men and the number of women in each group are the same, the colour of their clothes determines the group each individual belongs to and their gender determines the sub-group they belong to.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes. There is the same number of people in each corresponding group in both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

So I might understand this in one reading, I would state the situation:
**There are 2 scenarios, 1 and 2. Each scenario has 2 variations, 1.1 and 1.2 for scenario 1, and, 2.1 and 2.2 for scenario 2.** **Variations 1.1 and 1.2 complement scenario 1, respectively the same as variations 2.1 and 2.2 complement scenario 2.**

So

> The number of people involved in the two sets of complementary variations are the same, respectively.

I understand there can be other solutions. This one sets well with me, so I offer  it in hope it will help.

Comment: That's weird. Your 15 minute old answer didn't show up until after I posted my comment. Anyway, you did a fantastic job of anticipating my prescription - nearly word perfect ;p

Comment: @ Phil Sweet... I'm sorry you didn't get first shot, or didn't you? I did not see your comment before i pushed ":post", or I would not have,

Comment: I should confess that I got more confused with this answer. I have already mentioned that 1.1 parallels/corresponds 2.1, and 1.2 parallels/corresponds 2.2. And the correspondence relation is, I assume, two-sided. Now I want to say that there are the same number of people in 1.1 and 2.1, and the same number of people in 1.2 and 22. @PhilSweet

Comment: You beat me by 15 minutes according to the time stamp, but I didn't get the update. They typically are a lot faster than that.